# Unity code works in the editor but does not work on Build C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I am aware that there are others with this same issue and no, their solutions didn't help in my case.

I am working on a final project for college and they force us to use Perforce Helix Client (which is pure hell by the way) for version control.

My group and I work day and night fixing issues in the editor. We then finally got to the part where we can test our build. The build works fine on our ends. (yes, we deleted the old build files in perforce and got the current build files)

Then, disaster struck and when our professor tested our game, our movement script didn't work and he gave us another chance but said that our grades cannot be any higher than a 70 for this assignment because of this.

Anyways, I'm not the one who made this script but I want to know if there is anything here that would cause the script not to work in the build.

For those who don't care for the back story-

Issue: Player won't move in build and console spams nullreference at us.

What was expected: Character moving around.

What we tried: Deleting past builds and redownloading the current build and check everything in the inspector

Movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody rb;

    private Vector3 moveInput;
    private Vector3 moveVelocity;
    private Vector3 mousePosition;
    

    private Camera mainCamera;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        mainCamera = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
   
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, mousePosition);
        if(distance > 2)
        {
            moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 40 * Time.smoothDeltaTime, 0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * 40 * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
            moveVelocity = moveInput * moveSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
        }
        

        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);


        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2000))
        {
            transform.LookAt(new Vector3(hit.point.x, transform.position.y, hit.point.z));
        }




    }

   void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = moveVelocity;
    }


}
```

Points Keeper:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PointsKeeper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int points = 0;
    public Text pointText;
    public GameObject toExpensiveText;
    public float expensiveTimer = 1.0f;

    public GameObject healthPage;
    public GameObject weaponPage;
    public GameObject modPage;

    public GameObject lifeBlocker;
    public GameObject lifeSector;
    public GameObject lifeDropChanceSector;

    public GameObject shieldBlocker;
    public GameObject shieldRegensector;

    public GameObject healthBlocker;
    public GameObject healthcapacitysector;

    private PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    public Sprite fullCell;
    public Sprite emptyCell;

    //Health Page
    private int healprice = 100;
    public Text healpriceText;
    public GameObject healButton;

    public int maxHealthLVL = 0; 
    private int maxHealthMAXLVL = 5; 
    private int maxHealthprice = 100;
    public Text maxhealthpricetext;
    public GameObject maxhealthButton;
    public Image[] maxhealthCells;


    public int healDropChanceLVL = 0;
    private int healdropchanceprice = 100;
  

    public int shieldcapacityLVL = 0;
    private int sheildcapacityPrice = 100;

    public int shieldRegenRateLVL = 0;

    public int lifeDropChanceLVL = 0;

    public int lifeCapacityLVL = 0;

    private int lifePrice;


 

    //Weapon Page

    //Mod Page

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        points = 0;
        playerHealth = FindObjectOfType<PlayerHealth>();
        toExpensiveText.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        pointText.text = points.ToString();
        healpriceText.text = healprice.ToString();
        maxhealthpricetext.text = maxHealthprice.ToString();

        maxHealthCellControl();
        

        if (lifeCapacityLVL >= 1)
        {
            lifeBlocker.SetActive(false);
            lifeSector.SetActive(true);
            lifeDropChanceSector.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        if (shieldcapacityLVL >= 1)
        {
            shieldBlocker.SetActive(false);
            shieldRegensector.SetActive(true);
        }
       
        if (playerHealth.playerHP == playerHealth.maxheart)
        {
            healthBlocker.SetActive(false);
            healthcapacitysector.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            healthBlocker.SetActive(true);
            healthcapacitysector.SetActive(false);
        }
        
        if(playerHealth.playerHP == playerHealth.maxheart)
        {
            healButton.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            healButton.SetActive(true);
        }


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            points = points + 100000;
        }
    }
    public void pointsGained(int pointsup)
    {
        points = points + pointsup;
    }

    public void healthPageOn()
    {
        healthPage.SetActive(true);
        modPage.SetActive(false);
        weaponPage.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void weaponPageOn()
    {
        healthPage.SetActive(false);
        modPage.SetActive(false);
        weaponPage.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void modPageOn()
    {
        healthPage.SetActive(false);
        modPage.SetActive(true);
        weaponPage.SetActive(false);
    }


    public void toExpensive()
    {

    }

    public void buyHeal()
    {
        if(points >= healprice)
        {
            points = points - healprice;
            healprice = healprice + 100;
            playerHealth.playerHP = playerHealth.playerHP + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            toExpensive();
        }
    }

    public void buyMaxHealth()
    {
        if (points >= maxHealthprice && maxHealthLVL < 5)
        {
            maxHealthLVL = maxHealthLVL + 1;
            points = points - maxHealthprice;
            playerHealth.maxheart = playerHealth.maxheart + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            toExpensive();
        }


        if (maxHealthLVL == 1)
        {
            maxHealthprice = 1000;
        }
        else if (maxHealthLVL == 2)
        {
            maxHealthprice = 2000;
        }
        else if (maxHealthLVL == 3)
        {
            maxHealthprice = 4000;
        } 
        else if (maxHealthLVL == 4)
        {
            maxHealthprice = 10000;
        } 
        else if (maxHealthLVL == 5)
        {
            maxhealthButton.SetActive(false);
            maxhealthpricetext.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void maxHealthCellControl()
    {
       
        for (int i = 0; i < maxhealthCells.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < maxHealthLVL)
            {
                maxhealthCells[i].sprite = fullCell;
            }
            else
            {
                maxhealthCells[i].sprite = emptyCell;
            }
            if (i < maxHealthMAXLVL)
            {
                maxhealthCells[i].enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                maxhealthCells[i].enabled = false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Also on a side note, any idea of how to fix the null reference would be nice.

Sorry if the question wasn't specific enough or if I didn't provide enough information. I'm still in shock and don't use this site very often.

Comment: Where does the null reference come from? Which line?. Can you paste the console output?

Comment: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PointsKeeper.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PointsKeeper.cx:79)`

Comment: Also check https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html for debugging, it could help running the code line by line.

Comment: You need to figure out which kind breaks. If you don't debug then at least at log lines inside your update function, to narrow down the problematic area.

Comment: I goofed up, gonna upload the other script sorry about that.

Comment: If you have a NullRefEx in a script you have to post this script, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Posted it, sorry about that.

Comment: How do you set PointsKeeper.pointText? Getting rid of the exception is easy, simply check pointText for null before accessing it, but this would result in displayed points not being updated.

Comment: Update: the person who made the points keeper script fixed the nullreference. Now we are still faced with the first issue of the character not moving in the build.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to get rid of the exception:

```
public void maxHealthCellControl()
    {
       if (maxhealthCells == null) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxhealthCells.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < maxHealthLVL)
            {
                maxhealthCells[i].sprite = fullCell;
            }
            else
            {
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate your speed based on `moveSpeed` which defaults to `0`.

If you set this public serialized field in the editor (inspector) your movement will work, but the serialized value might not be stored in build (depending on your initialization of the player).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up redoing the entire movement system. Thanks for the help tho!